# Thermocouple measured okay, but replacing it fixed the problem?

Tags: furnace, testing, thermocouple

So the pilot on my furnace wouldn't stay lit. I tested the thermocouple with my multimeter and got 29 millivolts which meant it was still working.
Assuming I was in over my head, I called the plumber who proceeded to change the thermocouple and now everything is fine. Family is warm, what more can you ask for?

Is it common for thermocouples to test fine but still not actually work? Everywhere I looked said over 25 millivolts means the thermocouple is fine and there must be a different problem.

Comment: What make/model is your furnace? Oil or gas? Where did you see the "over 25mv" requirement?

Comment: It's a new yorker. Gas. Here's one site that said 25 https://www.google.com/amp/s/highperformancehvac.com/how-test-thermocouple-multi-meter/amp/?client=ms-android-metropcs-us but they all did.

Comment: Suggestion: good thermocouple, bad connections.

Comment: @keshlam I unscrewed it and cleaned that end too (as one video suggested it could need cleaning too) reattached it, and no dice.

Comment: I meant electrical connections. If it works when removed but not when installed, that suggests there is something wrong with either how it is installed or what it is connected to (intermittent wire, for example)

Comment: @keshlam plumber touched nothing besides the thermocouple

Comment: What is the voltage of the new thermocouple?

Comment: @wallyk to add insult to injury it's less than the old one. 27mv.

Comment: Ha ha!  Can you get your hands on a 1/2 ohm (or so) resistor?  I am thinking of a load test for the new and old thermocouples.

Comment: @wallyk I don't think i have a half ohm. 1 ohm is probably the smallest I have. The old one has been trashed.

Comment: Any reasons for the downvotes?

Answer (score 3):

Voltage is not a universal indicator of effectiveness.   Ask anyone with a dead car battery.

Like many providers of power, it is not uncommon for them to have a reasonable "open-circuit" (no-load) voltage, only to fail when the load attempts to draw its ordinary and reasonable amount of current.   That qualifies as "defective" and the voltmeter did not tell the tale.

People use voltmeters because it is easy, not because it is thorough.  Examining current is more useful but harder, because it must be detected "in-line", and particularly with DC, that means splicing something in series with the current flow.  Or unhooking the load and hooking up a dummy load of known value.  Or permanently installing an "ammeter shunt", a resistor of known and low value, and measuring a small voltage drop across it.  We just had a $10,000 problem because of not knowing a large engine's normal cranking current, because there is not ammeter in the starting circuit.  Putting one in is hard.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment to the other answer, everyone who suggests this test performed it under no load. Do you have reason to think that this 25mv circuit would be a high current draw?

Comment: And most people who check car batteries measure them under no load. Like I say they do it because it's easy, not because it's the best test. **Of course** the thermocouple has a load of some kind, otherwise it would be unneeded.  I'm sure the load is right-sized for the thermocouple, so it's "a high current draw" from the  thermocouple's perspective!

Answer (score 2):

Huh, I've changed a lot of thermocouples but never heard of measuring the voltage like that. Did your plumber measure voltage?

As for what's going on, we can't know without the old thermocouple to test, but here's some possible causes in rough order of likelihood:

1. Inadequate flame.  And the plumber adjusted this when changing the thermocouple.
2. Suboptimal thermocouple position and/or flame director -- corrected by plumber as part of replacement.
3. Dirty/corroded contacts on old thermocouple.
4. Intermittent break in old thermocouple.  Bending or expansion causes an open circuit.
5. Draft condition that was corrected by the plumber (misplaced vent louvers, covers, etc.)
6. The thermocouple measures okay, open circuit, but not under enough load to actually drive the valve.  (No-load Voltage testing is often misleading.  This is true in a multitude of trades/scenarios.)

---

For pilot light issues, I use this rough checklist:

- Is gas actually supplied and clean? No sputtering, sparks or off-colors indicating water or contamination?
- Is the flame adequately sized to not blow out easily?
- Is the thermocouple properly positioned in the flame?
- Are metal flakes or water droplets present and could fresh falling flakes/drops strike the pilot flame?  If yes, the whole unit is usually due to be swapped.
- Is there a gusty draft condition present?
- Does the unit operate correctly otherwise?
- Was maintenance recently done?  If so, check for a loose or misinstalled or damaged thermocouple.
- If all of the above is okay, replace the thermocouple.

Comment: was it a thermocouple or a pilot generator? It makes a difference

Comment: I cleaned the thermocoupler and it still didn't work. I watched the plumber the whole 5 minutes he was there and he did not adjust anything else. He did not test the old one at all. Only suggestion 6 got me to think for a minute that you were on to something, but all the sites and videos I saw where people demonstrate this test were done under no load. But thank you for the answer, maybe it will help someone else troubleshooting in the future. +1

Comment: @d.george although I am certain this is a thermocoupler, your comment got me to check around and I found this video where the suggested milivolts for thermocoupler is 75. https://youtu.be/--nI0u_k9kc (as opposed to the thermopile). So now I'm getting really curious as to what the newly installed one is registering. Do you have experience with testing these?

Comment: @user6591, I daresay you haven't ruled out an intermittent (#4), as those can be very tricky.  Anyway, measure the voltage of your new thermocouple and maybe post a picture of it.

Comment: I think getting 29 mv rules that out for the most part, but you never know. I will be measuring it soon. I'll check back in.

Comment: @d.george, It would make a difference to the output voltage, sure.  But how would it change the debug steps above?  (Especially as no pro seems to actually check the voltage.)

Comment: Voltage on new one is 27mv:) lesson learned. Don't test. Just switch. A five dollar investment that'll save $100. (But I really wish I could understand what it really was)

Comment: Testing is a good thing, but you must know enough to be cost effective.  Testing an appliance thermocouple is generally not cost effective, as you learned.  Anywho, your problem was most likely #4.  It takes a special kind of skill to track down intermittents, and measuring an okay voltage on the bench will not cut it.  Also, call the plumber up and ask him if he adjusted anything. Repositioning or bending could be done in just a second or two, and you might have missed it. (It's often automatic, and pros do it all the time without even thinking or realizing it as a separate step.)

Answer (score 1):

I rarely tested the voltage of a thermocouple since it was not cost effective from a labor cost standpoint. If you are wondering,  Intermittent thermocouple problems can occur if the pilot flame heats the lower 1/3 of the thermocouple. This heating can cause the dissimilar metals inside the thermocouple to break apart temporarily dropping the output voltage to zero. When the bottom cools the connection is remade so that the thermocouple will work when relit

Comment: Interesting, thank you. This is along the lines of what I was hoping to hear.

Comment: I have never in  my life heard such B...S... answers. . Just answer the questions if you can and if you can't don't say anything.Get a life.